# How to find out where reference to primary key is used in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 with primary key called `ID` which then is used by multiple tables around the database as foreign key. How to find out by which tables it is used? I'm trying to delete that record but it's complaining that `ID` is in use.

Or maybe there's an easy way to delete all referenced records from whole database just by giving database that `ID`? Right now I'm going for each table (that I know has that ID as foreign key) and deleting records that correspond to that particular ID but if there's better/simpler way to find it and delete all at once with simple code then that would best idea.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

MS SQL benefits from being able to describe itself.  In particular, there is a series of views that begin with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

To get an idea of where your field is used, try :-

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
```

Comment: Can I get same information on particular table's column?

Comment: man, thx, thats cool, solved everything :)

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at the tables **[sysobjects](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)** and **[sysforeignkeys](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177604.aspx)**, you can get all foreignkeys that reference your table.

Try this untested Statement:

```
select a.name as ConstraintName, f.name as FromTable, t.name as ToTable 
from sysobjects a, sysobjects f, sysobjects t, sysforeignkeys b
where a.id=b.constid and f.id=b.fkeyid and t.id=b.rkeyid and t.name= 'Yourtable'
```

Comment: Works as designed just like Paul's answer (which is a bit simpler).

Answer (score 8):

```
select constraintColumns.* from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE as constraintColumns
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS as constraints on constraintColumns.CONSTRAINT_NAME = constraints.CONSTRAINT_NAME
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE as keys on constraints.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = keys.CONSTRAINT_NAME
where keys.TABLE_NAME = 'yourTableWithThePrimaryKeyColumn';
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the relation ***cascade on delete*** if the main table has an ownership relationship with other tables, meaning that by deleting the main row, other dependent rows in other tables should be deleted.

That's an option that might apply to your scenario.

> The REFERENCES clauses of the CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements
> support the ON DELETE and ON UPDATE clauses. Cascading actions can
> also be defined by using the Foreign Key Relationships dialog box:
>
> [ ON DELETE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT } ]
>
> [ ON UPDATE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT } ]

More at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#CASCADE      http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit. It seems like it's a setting for SQL Server rather then normal SQL command? Will it affect all tables or just particular ? Can you give example? Your answer seems good but just lack information for further reference.

Comment: Please don't give such generic - and dangerous! - advices.

Comment: @JahanZinedine include the related parts of the links you've posted as a comment. This explanation is lacking the way it currently is.